# Computing profile confidence intervals for a regression line

Tags: r

Simulate some data

```
n       <- 50
beta0   <- 2
beta1   <- 0.32
x       <- runif(n=n, min=0, max=5)
mu      <- exp(beta0 + beta1 * x)
y       <- rpois(n=n, lambda=mu)
data    <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
plot(data$x, data$y)
```

Apply a Poisson regression

```
glm.pois <- glm(formula= y ~ x, data=data, family=poisson(link="log"))
summary(glm.pois)
```

Compute profile 95% CI

```
(pCI <- confint(glm.pois))
nice.xs <- sort(data$x)
pred.pCI   <- apply(t(pCI), 1, FUN=function(x){exp( x[1]+x[2]*nice.xs)})
```

Compute 95% CI using the SE

```
new.dat <- data.frame(phat = predict(glm.pois, type="response"),
                      x  = data$x)
new.dat <- new.dat[with(new.dat, order(x)), ]
ilink <- poisson()$linkinv

## Add fit and se.fit on the link scale
new.dat <- bind_cols(new.dat, 
     setNames(as_tibble(predict(glm.pois, new.dat, 
                           se.fit = TRUE)[1:2]), 
              c('fit_link','se_link')))
new.dat <- mutate(new.dat,
                  fit  = ilink(fit_link),
                  right_upr = ilink(fit_link + (2 * se_link)),
                  right_lwr = ilink(fit_link - (2 * se_link)))
```

Plot

```
ggplot(data=new.dat, aes(x=x, y= phat)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(x=x, ymin =right_lwr, ymax = right_upr), 
                fill = "darkgreen", alpha=0.3) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x=nice.xs, ymin = pred.pCI[,1], ymax = pred.pCI[,2]), 
                fill = "darkorange", alpha=0.3) +
    theme_classic(base_size=15)
```

My question is why are the profile 95% CI (orange ribbon) so large? I imagine I am computing them wrong but I don't know where my mistake is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very strong correlation between the intercept and slope:

```r
cov2cor(vcov(glm.pois))
            (Intercept)          x
(Intercept)   1.0000000 -0.9147526
x            -0.9147526  1.0000000
```

Your profile CIs, which are computing (`logistic(intercept_lwr + slope_lwr*x)` and `logistic(intercept_upr + slope_upr*x)`, are ignoring this correlation.

It's not easy to compute profile confidence intervals on derived values (i.e., on quantities other than the parameters themselves).

Comment: Great, thank you. I imagined this was the case but couldn't find it explicitly stated anywahere (maybe I was looking in the wrong places).